# Not getting proper time by using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: android, simpledateformat, utc

I am trying to convert date from JSON which is in UTC format to my Local time.

I am getting time as `10/27/2013 5:58:02 PM` which I need to convert to my local time which is `+5:30`.

But instead I am getting `10/27/2013 6:28:02`.

My code is

```
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss a");
    SimpleDateFormat longDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss");
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        String formattedDate="";
        try
        {
            Date myDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(mDateAndTime);

            formattedDate = longDateFormat.format(myDate);
        } catch (ParseException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: if you remove the line... simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
may be it works..I am not sure because I cannot test it. Please give it a try

Comment: thnx for reply, but i am getting 10/27/2013 0:58:02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will helps you:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
SimpleDateFormat longDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
try
{
    Date myDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("10/25/2013 02:00:00 PM");
    String now = simpleDateFormat.format(myDate.getTime());
    System.out.println("12 hour format : " + now);
    String time24 = longDateFormat.format(simpleDateFormat.parse(now));
    System.out.println("24 hour format : " + time24);
} catch (ParseException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Nope, i am getting 10/27/2013 0:58:02 AM +0530. What is "Z" here?

Comment: thnx for your effort but its not working. I will try something else tommorow